# не работает выбор через input и if

Tags: python, python-3.x

При вводе(через input) 1 и 0 все ровно выдает 1

```
class FirstClass:
    def FirstDef(self):
        print('0 или 1:')
        inpt = input()
        if inpt == 0:
            print('Hello, 0')
        elif inpt != 1:
            print('Hello, 1')

p = FirstClass()
p.FirstDef()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У тебя в elif inpt != 1, что можно перевести как - "Если inpt **не** равно 1."

Просто измени != на ==

UPD

Также возможно ещё проблема в типе получаемого значения

Попробуй `inpt = int(input())`. Это преобразует получаемое значение из input в целочисленный тип int

Comment: Проблема не возможно, а однозначно в типе, ведь `input` возвращает строчку и плохая идея сравнивать ее с числом. Что условие надо поправить, это тоже верно.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FirstClass:
    def FirstDef(self):
        inpt = input('0 или 1:')
        if inpt == '0':
            print('Hello, 0')
        elif inpt == '1':
            print('Hello, 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()` по умолчанию будет считывать строку. Тут есть два пути:

1. Преобразовать полученные данные в int: `int(input())`
2. Сравнивать со строкой: `if unpt == '1'`